# How should we deal with non-English Stack Overflow sites?

Tags: discussion, languages, international-sites

I see that a Stack Overflow site in Portuguese was launched, and that there are plans for other languages as well. My mother language is not English (nor Portuguese), but even if a site in my mother language will be launched (which seems to be planned), I think I would rarely use that site and rather stick to the English site. Even if I happened to post a question on a non-English site, I will most likely end up cross posting the same question on the English site since it is much more likely to receive attention.

My concern is that there would be a huge amount of duplicates among the sites, but each site will have an inferior set of questions and answers compared to that of the English site. There will be a significant amount of reinventing (reasking/reanswering) the wheel (a question), which is not what a programmer is supposed to do. Even just within the single English Stack Overflow site, there are plenty of duplicate questions, among which answers are split over. With localized sites, this would be even worse.

If these sites are launched, how should we deal with them? What is the correct attitude?

- Ignore them and stick to the English site?
- Stick to the mother's tongue site?
- Primarily ask on the mother's tongue site, but often leave a duplicate on the English site just in case it does not get answered?
- Always leave the same questions on as many sites as you can handle the language?
- Randomly ask on any site that you feel like for that day?

I have some more questions:

- Will cross-posting among different sites be appreciated?
- Will there be a systematic mechanism to link duplicate questions across the sites?
- Will a duplicate on another site be a reason for closing a question?

My personal thoughts is that, although I hate English imperialism/centrism, things would be more effective if people over the world communicate on a single site using a single natural language, and we have to admit that the lingua Franca as of today is English. I do not believe that any other site will grow into a usable site as the English one.

Comment: @rene Thanks for the link. Although, the OP there seems to be a native English speaker, and its points look somewhat racist.

Comment: This one is more neutral but has an answer from me.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222511/why-do-we-need-a-stack-overflow-in-portuguese

Comment: Related: [Do the benefits of having SO in multiple languages outweigh the risks involved?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194959/do-the-benefits-of-having-so-in-multiple-languages-outweigh-the-risks-involved) and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/

Comment: You seem to be very comfortable with English; your writing is better than *many* native speakers. But I'd wager that most of the users and potential users on the non-English sites are not even close to your level.

Comment: * When a site also includes a non-English (EN) site, such as Portugues, I like having the sub-domain pt.stackoverflow.com . I just wish the navigation from stackoverflow.com home included the different language sites top of fold.

Comment: I looked a bit into Stack Overflow in Spanish. There is almost no content, some duplicating English answers, some also linking to English SO. I really hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 12):

Wikipedia has long been in an analogous situation—lots of language sites that provide encyclopedic information about topics in many different languages, with the largest Wikipedia being English's.  It's quite possible to contribute to Wikipedia by translating articles or parts of articles from one language into another.  Since translations reach different audiences, the same should also be allowed on Stack Overflow.  You would be contributing by posting on as many language sites as you find worthwhile.

Comment: That is a very good point. Under this view, a pure translation post of a question and/or answers from one language to another should be encouraged.

Comment: @sawa the purpose of Stack Overflow is to provide useful information to people.  A pure-translation post furthers this purpose.

Comment: Personally I hate any programming that does not use English identifiers and such, hopefully this won't encourage such things. Recently my company was fused by another company. Thank god most of the applications from both sides were English (and the other company was *French*, can you imagine that?)

Comment: Wikipedia might not be the best example. On SE the success of a question and the probability of a good answer is based on how much attention it receives in the first few hours (and on StackOverflow, in the first few minutes). On Wikipedia, an article can gradually be built over months or years.

Comment: A Wikipedia article can be improved by anyone with enough language skills, by reading official external sources and adding from them to the article, as an ideal Wikipedia article should have zero extra information/opinion/explanation. SO, however, relies on a few very skilled users in the answering of interesting and difficult questions. If they are busy at the moment on a different language site, it can affect the quality time they spend on the main English site. English is not may native language, and I usually prefer to have sites in my own language, but programming is an exception for me.

Comment: @vsz, good answers are viewed and modified over many days and I've learned many Computer Science gems from years-old SO posts.  Good answers really can come months or years later.  Better to have Users translate posts than sit around waiting for a question they can answer to come by, or post junk.

Comment: I want to see the ability for us to reference a different language site, import the answer, and translate/paraphrase in the new language. For example, if I reference an English answer on SO, I can link to the source, import the answer automatically, and then translate/paraphrase in Portugues.

Comment: The readership of Wikipedia is far different from the readership of StackOverflow. Computer programming is geography-independent. And the vast majority of programmers, whether they admit it or not, know enough English to Google questions they have and read pages in English, because that just happens to be the language in which the majority of programming-related content is written in. Wikipedia, on the other hand, addresses a general audience, from the schoolgirl who wants to learn about an insert living in her country, to a grandpa reading up on some local political event.

Comment: Wikipedia has inter-language links sidebar. Readers can start reading in one language and go to another language to read the same article easily. This is not the case with SO today, as we don't have cross links between languages. It's even not encouraged to post questions on multiple sites!

Answer (score 2):

How do we deal with cross-site duplicates? By not creating the opportunity for them to arise.

Like it or not, programming is very much an English affair. Jeff Atwood wrote very convincingly on why [programmers should just "STFU and learn English"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-ugly-american-programmer/).

I'm not a native English speaker. When I wanted to become a competent programmer, I quickly realized that the best resources are not available in my native language, but in English, the de facto universal language for software engineering. It wasn't even difficult - IT English is significantly easier than English in general, and its vocabulary is far smaller. Moreover, a bunch of programming concepts are not even translated in most languages, but are just borrowed (e.g. "[thunking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)", the vast majority of acronyms).

One's native language is an arbitrary distinction. Why split communities based on that? Instead, we should focus on developing valuable content, while its vehicle, the language, is one that the largest majority of programmers around the world are familiar with - English.

Answer (score 2):

Per [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/), it seems that you should post on whichever one you feel most comfortable on.

If your English is good enough that you feel that you can post on English SO, by all means, do so. (Yours is.)

If you feel that you would do better in your native language, then you should post there. Or, if you just feel like furthering the site, post there.

I think that if you asked on your native language site and did not get a satisfactory answer, then you could take it to SO and no-one would complain. Think of it like first asking on a child meta, and then taking it to MSE.

One more thing: If you've asked on SO and gotten a great answer, you can translate that Q&A into your native language, and get some good content there too.