# Spanish Stack Overflow: how to deal with cross-site duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, languages, international-sites

I've [read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271998/fluent-in-spanish-were-hiring-a-community-manager-for-a-spanish-stack-overflow) the Spanish Stack Overflow is about to be created. (I haven't made up my mind whether that seems a good idea or not; but that's a different matter).

Consider the following very plausible situation. I regularly participate on both sites. I see a question in site A that I know has been answered in site B. Let's also assume that the important part of the answer is the code (rather than comments or explanations). How to proceed? Of course marking as duplicate is ruled out (or is it?), the two questions belonging to different sites. I see at least two sensible approaches:

1. Post an answer in site A, essentially reproducing the answer from site B, with due reference to the original site B's answerer.
2. Post an answer in site A, consisting of a very brief introduction to clarify any minor differences followed by a link to the answer in site B. Even if site A's asker cannot read B language, they surely can read the code.

I think this situation will happen a lot, so we should have a clear policy on this.

Comment: I'm sure others asked about this already, just with portuguese SO.

Comment: I'm certain that similar issues have been discussed previously... but I couldn't find any answer to this specific question for Spanish or Portuguese

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270047/cross-posting-between-localized-stack-overflow-versions http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252199/how-should-we-deal-with-non-english-stack-overflow-sites

Comment: @Deduplicator First link is about cross-asking, not about cross-similar answers. Second link, although related with my question, does not answer it

Comment: If you think that the code is all that's important in an answer and that any explanations are not particularly important then you have those two reversed.  The explanations in an answer are what is important, code is secondary.

Comment: @Servy Code _secondary_... in StackOverflow?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @Servy Well, let's restrict my (meta) question then to those questions that are essentially answered with code

Comment: @LuisMendo It should be *very* rare to find a question that is answered *well* with *just* code.  You would cease to be discussing a generalized policy.

Comment: @Servy In many cases the code speaks for itself (as it should) and a brief introduction in language A followed by a link to B's answer _could_ be enough. I'm thinking about those cases.

Comment: @LuisMendo If you're asserting that a particular question doesn't merit an explanation then obviously you don't need to explain anything for that question.  I would assert however that most questions *do* merit an explanation, and that such explanations should be in the appropriate language.

Comment: I have a suggestion: Convert everything of value from the localized sites, but don't put anything from the English version to the localized version, hopefully that will contribute to the demise of this horrible idea. I'm sure that the evil geniuses behind this idea are native English speakers that never really have experienced the issues of multilinguality.

Comment: at the very least, ["Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251475/839601)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In SOpt we do a mix of those.

The most common thing is for us to provide an explanation of the solution - one of our own - and if an explanation exists in the original, sometimes we translate that and append to ours. After that, we always provide a link to the original answer.

I am going to provide two examples - I believe Spanish speakers will be able to understand the content in Portuguese.

An example of a very short answer with a reference to SO: [Erro plugin Eclipse Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25919/erro-plugin-eclipse-android/25921#25921);

An example of a more average sized answer with a reference to SO: [Qual a diferença entre as funções var name = function() e function name()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-var-name-function-e-function-name/13365#13365)

And if you want to see a wealth of examples of how we do that - in SOpt we call the original Stack Overflow SOen. [Just search for "SOen" on SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=soen).

The other way around, taking an answer from SOpt to SOen, is rare. I can only relate to one case (I know a handful more have happened). I believe it will be more common with SOes, though. In such cases I would keep doing as we are doing: provide your own explanation, append a translation of the original if you think it would improve the answer, and then provide a link.

As a personal choice of style I always provide my translations inside a quote block (starting the paragraph with a >).

Comment: Very clear answer! Thanks! It's good to know from someone with experience in SOpt. And yes, your linked answers were easy to follow for a Spaniard. Spoken Portuguese is a different matter altogether :-) I'll wait for a while in case more answers show up

Comment: Are SOpt and SOen the "official" abbreviations? I find them confusing to read, but they seem to be slightly more common than pt.SO

Comment: @Stijn AFAIK they are not official - we just started calling them this way and the names stuck.

Answer (score -2):

How do we deal with cross-site duplicates? By not creating the opportunity for them to arise.

Like it or not, programming is very much an English affair. Jeff Atwood wrote very convincingly on why [programmers should just "STFU and learn English"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-ugly-american-programmer/).

I'm not a native English speaker. When I wanted to become a competent programmer, I quickly realized that the best resources are not available in my native language, but in English, the de facto universal language for software engineering. So I learned English. It wasn't even difficult - IT English is significantly easier than English in general, and its vocabulary is far smaller. Moreover, a bunch of programming concepts are not even translated in most languages, but are just borrowed (e.g. "[thunking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)", or the vast majority of acronyms).

One's native language is an arbitrary distinction. Why split communities based on that? Instead, we should focus on developing valuable content, while its vehicle, the language, is one that the largest majority of programmers around the world happen to be familiar with - English.

Comment: I agree with most of what you say (I'm not sure I agree to the point of telling anyone to "STFU and learn English", though). It's an interesting discussion. However, this answers a question slighlty different from what I asked

Comment: So... Out of curiosity, if you were going to post this answer here, why did you put the same one word for word on the old question asking about the Portuguese site? That one's been pretty much dormant minus an edit here recently.